# Unable to SSH to Pi 3: All ports are closed

Tags: pi-3, ssh, macos

I have a Raspberry Pi 3. It's brand new. Didn't connect before. It has the NOOBS-software already pre-installed on its SD card (didn't do it myself. It was included in the purchase. I've connected my HDMI + Power + Network cable of the PI with my Mac OSsierra.

After some networkconfiguration (about sharing wifi with ethernet) I was able to find the IP of my PI and I was able to ping.

```
arp -na | grep -i b8:27:eb
? (192.168.2.2) at b8:27:eb:72:26:48 on bridge100 ifscope [bridge]
```

The ping:

```
$ ping 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.342 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.303 ms
```

I'm sure this is the IP of my PI thanks to an IP-scanner. [image]

I tried to ssh (default credentials were described in the manual:

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.2.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

Now I checked which ports were open on my PI:

```
$ nmap 192.168.2.2

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-25 13:47 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.2
Host is up (0.00043s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.2.2 are closed
```

Now I'm stuck. Is it because there is just the NOOBS software preinstalled and not already some real operating system with openssh?
Is there still a way to connect to my Raspberry Pi 3 from my MAC and perfrom the installation over there?

Comment: You need to enable SSH (this is a recent change) in the menu under preferences or via commandline run sudo raspi-config (option 5 IIRC).

Comment: @SteveRobillard Hmm so I really need to connect the Pi with a monitor + keyboard the first time. Because I don't have those over here atm.

Comment: or add an empty ssh file to the boot partition which you should be able to do from a pc or mac.